Orthogonal Basis and Projection Matrix for a Plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$
Let $W$ be the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by the Cartesian equation $x + y - 2z = 0$.

Find an orthogonal basis, $B_{W}$, for the subspace $ W $ and an orthogonal basis, $ B $, for $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ that extends $ B_W $.

Let $P: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the orthogonal projection onto $ W $. Find $[P] $, the matrix representation of $ P $.


I am not sure how to solve part 1 of exercise. Could you please help me with it? I am not sure if the selection of x=0 and y=1 is valid and then the other selection of x=1 and y=0 i valid as well
Here is my attempt
For a first vector in ( W ), let $x = 1 $ and $ y = 0 $. Then:
$$
x + y - 2z = 1 + 0 - 2z = 0 \Rightarrow z = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
This gives us the vector $ \mathbf{v}_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix} $.
For a second vector, let $ x =0$ and $ y = 1 $. Then:
$$
x + y - 2z = 0 + 1 - 2z = 0 \Rightarrow z = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
This gives us the vector $\mathbf{v}_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix} $.
Now we have two vectors, $ \mathbf{v}_1 $and $\mathbf{v}_2 $, which are linearly independent and belong to ( W ). To find an orthogonal basis, we can apply the Gram-Schmidt process:
Let $\mathbf{u}_1 = \mathbf{v}_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix} $.
For the next vector:
$$
\mathbf{u}_2 = \mathbf{v}_2 - \frac{\mathbf{v}_2 \cdot \mathbf{u}_1}{\mathbf{u}_1 \cdot \mathbf{u}_1} \mathbf{u}_1.
$$
We will compute each of these products to obtain $ \mathbf{u}_2 $, and then normalize both vectors to get the orthogonal basis $B_W $ in ( W ).
Extending the orthogonal basis ( B_W ) to an orthogonal basis ( B ) for $ \mathbb{R}^3 $:
To extend the basis of the subspace ( W ) to a basis of $ \mathbb{R}^3 $, we need to add a vector orthogonal to both vectors in $ B_W $ (that is, orthogonal to the plane ( W )). This can be done by taking the normal vector of ( W ), given by the coefficients of the equation $ x + y - 2z = 0 $, which is $\mathbf{n} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix} $.

You do not need to normalize. An orthogonal basis is just fine for this application; you do not need an orthonormal basis. Other than omitting the computation of Gram-Schmidt, it seems to me you've done the exercise perfectly.  (Personally, I would multiply the vectors through by $2$ to get rid of the fractions.) What is your specific question?

@TedShifrin my question is if the selection of the x and y is correct to do the process at the beginning of the proof

Sure. Any (non-parallel) solutions  $x$ and $y$ you choose will be fine. There is no single right answer. $(1,-1,0)$ would be fine for one of them, too.

Simpler solution for $v_1,v_2$: take any non-zero vector $v_1\in W$, e.g. $v_1=\pmatrix{1\-1\0}$. Then, take any non-zero vector $v_2\in v_1^\perp\cap W$, e.g. $v_2=\pmatrix{1\1\1}$.
